# Set model in one view and access it in another - backbone

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, models, router

**View1**

```
this.orderDataModel.set({
    channel_id: channel_id,
    channel_type: channel_type
}, { silent: true });
```

Say i set my model in one view can i access it in another view ?

**View2**

```
this.orderDataModel = new orderDataModel();
console.log(this.orderDataModel);
console.log(self.orderDataModel.get("channel_id")); //undefined
```

I get no properties ?

EDIT:

I am calling the second view via the router

```
manifestDetails: function (id) {
    "use strict";
    var optionsManifest = { manifestId: id };
    if (this.manifestDetail) {
        this.manifestDetail.initialize(optionsManifest)
    } else {
        this.manifestDetail = new manifestDetailsView(optionsManifest);
    }

    this.manifestDetail.render();
}
```

Comment: Yare calling it's `initialize` method manually which seems kind of wrong to me. It's supposed to be called automatically when the view is actually created. Also you shared little code from `view1` and `view2` but there is no code where those views are initialized.. please share more code...

Answer (score 3):

As long as both views are attached with the same model, both of them should be able to access the model attributes.
What have possibly happend, is that either they're not using the same model, or maybe you are trying to print the change before it actually happend.

As you can see in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9vfrhmL/1/

(click on the red name to change it).

As you can see, when you click on the text only the second view is changing. It happens since only the second view is actually listening to the changes in the model, while the first one is numb (even though they refference to the same model!).
Therefore, adding the `listenTo` to each of the views will solve the problem easily:

```
var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#myName1',
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model,"change",this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.text(this.model.get("name"))
    }
});

var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#myName2',
    events:{
        'click' : 'changeName'
    },
    changeName: function(){
        this.model.set({name:"vini"});
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model,"change",this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.text(this.model.get("name"))
    }
});

var model = new Backbone.Model();

var view1 = new View1({model:model});

var view2 = new View2({model:model});

model.set({name:"mor"})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5h9Les7q/5/

And anyway, using `silent:true` will cause the change event not to be fired, I think it is not neccessary in this case.

Comment: i am rendering the new view using the router i think that is why not able to view the model